# UITableView performance degrading after adding subviews on cell iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, uitableview

In my application, I'm adding a label and two buttons on cell of UItableView [I have not created a separate cell class]. I'm adding these to cell and not cell.contentview. After I run my application on IPhone, the tableview cell rendering after I move the cells up-down, is very jerky. Is it because I'm not adding the views on cell.contentView or because I've not created a custom class for cell?

Can anybody please help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: as texmex5 points you may have problem with reusing your cells correctly (it is often crucial for tableview performance). But to find actual problems we need to see your code...

Answer (score 0):

Cells are reused so make sure you do it within the `if(!cell) {}` block.

Answer (score 0):

Create a parent `UIView` that contains your label and buttons. Set `cell.contentView` to this parent view.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, the real problem was too many NSLog statements. I removed them, now it works fine. Thanks texmex5, Alex Reynolds and Vladimir for trying to help.